# unexpected result sorting list with mixed items tuples and lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
tmp = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (4, 5, 6),
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12],
]

print tmp
tmp.sort()
print tmp
```

results in:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Apparently lists get precedence over tuples.
Is this correct?

Comment: You could use `tmp.sort(key= sum)`

Comment: Or `key=tuple` to make them all tuples for comparison purposes. But what do you mean *"is this correct"*?

Comment: It is “correct” as in that it follows Python 2’s specific implementation that a tuple always compares larger than a list.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), this is a CPython2 implementation detail. Not all flavors of Python2 are required to behave this way.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2,

In the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in,

> Most other objects of built-in types compare unequal unless they are the same object; the choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one execution of a program.

But I believe it's implementation independent:

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type
>   names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison
>   are ordered by their address.

In Python 3, this is fixed, so that comparing tuples and lists gives

`TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > list()`.

Comment: if this helps, please accept as an answer, otherwise let me know the problem you are having :)